# Using File manager with Second Hard Drive

Tags: ubuntu, files, hard-disk

I am going to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a new hard drive and install my current HD as a second drive. (It will stay there until I can copy over my */home* directory to the new drive.)

My questions is, if I am viewing files using a file manager (e.g., Gnome Commander), and am copying from my old drive to the new one, will I need to unmount the second hard drive before closing the file mgr or will it do it automatically? I don't want to lose any of the data on the second HD. (I am 'assuming' Gnome Commander would automatically mount it; perhaps not a good assumption?)

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I edited it to show the proper version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Easily. All the modern file managers are able to scan other hard drives for any readable partitions (e.g. ntfs, fat, ext etc) . It is possible to safely copy data from the hard disk.

In case it is not getting automatically mounted, you can first get the UUID or device details by doing a 
`sudo blkid` and then using `umount` to mount the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed. I guess have the rest of the week lined-up.